# Office Word Interop - document history

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, docx

I am having the following problem - I want my Word to get a document saved in a .doc format and extract a specific version of it, and convert it to PDF.

The actual opening and conversion works fine with this code:

```
Application wordApp = null;
lock (typeof (Application))
{
    OfficeWordHelper helper = new OfficeWordHelper();
    wordApp = helper.OpenApplicationWithFile(source);

    wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref target, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF,
                                  ref unknown, ref unknown, ref unknown,
                                  ref unknown, ref unknown, ref unknown,
                                  ref unknown, ref unknown, ref unknown,
                                  ref unknown, ref unknown, ref unknown,
                                  ref unknown, ref unknown);
    wordApp = helper.CloseApplication(wordApp);
}
```

However I don't see a way to get to a specific version of the document, and operate on that specific version, for example saving it to pdf. Would someone have any tips or code snippets?

Comment: What you mean with creating a specific version? You mean doing something like this?: opening doc1.docx, adding/removing some bits and saving all these changes to doc2.docx and to doc2.pdf?

Comment: No, I mean when I have a document that has been edited twice and contains both of those revisions. I would like to extract for example the first changeset and work with that.

Comment: OK. You expect Word to generate as many documents as times you saved the given file? For example: you edited this file since it was created 50 times and you are looking for a way to retrieve the document as it was after each of these editions? Like the left-hand-side panel which pops-up when you close Word wrongly, offering you the last versions?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you for your time reading into my question, I can see it might have caused some confusion

Comment: No problem. Yes, perhaps you should write it such that the ideas are transmitted better. Regarding this specific functionality, I haven't ever tried to do that (not sure if is even possible/reliable enough); what is clear is that will have a pretty limited scope of application. In your case, I would better rely on a more simpistic approach (e.g., telling Word the exact contents of each version; for example, via bookmarks) rather than spending time on figuring out how to deal (if possible) with a so complicated feature. Sorry but I cannot be of help.